# Meteor: execute jQuery code on every "change"

Tags: meteor

I have an app where I want to execute a jQuery `equalize()` function on some `DIV` boxes every time my "pages" change. At the moment I have the code inside my main layout's `render()` function but it is executed only once the user reloads the whole page. I tried to use `autorun` but this didn't work out either.

Meteor 1.0.3.1 + iron:router

**EDIT:**

I have different page views with routes (e.g. /home, /about-us, /terms, ...) and once the user navigates to a page (meaning follows a route to another view) the code should be executed.

Comment: You need to clarify what is this change. Is it a Session variable, a Collection, a timed event?

Comment: thanks - I edited my question and I hope this clears up what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [iron-router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md), then try this:

```
Router.onAfterAction( 
  function(){
   // select divs and apply equalize
  },
  {
     only: ['admin']
     // or except: ['routeOne', 'routeTwo']
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [hooks](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#hooks) in IronRouter. Add an `onBeforeAction` hook to your router configuration to apply it to all routes.

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    //dostuff
})
```