# Meteor: Where to place $('#modal').modal() call to automatically show the same modal on many routes?

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, iron-router

I am developing an application with Meteor. On several pages I want to programmatically show a bootstrap-3 modal when the user navigates to that page. The modal will give instructions for how to use respective page. The user has the possibility to disable this behaviour.

After reading this [Meteor: execute jQuery code on every "change"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626064/meteor-execute-jquery-code-on-every-change) I thought the best way to do this is in iron-router's hooks.

```
StepController = RouteController.extend({
  onAfterAction: function() {
    var userSettings = Meteor.user().profile.settings;
    if(userSettings.showHelp) {
      $('#modal').modal();
    }
  }
});
```

The modal shows, but it renders the page unusable, as the modal doesn't respond to any attempts to close it.

In the comments I read that the router shouldn't be used for anything but routing the user and related security checks.

So all in all suggested places I found on Stack Overflow  to put the modal call are:

- Iron Router hooks
- template helper
- template rendered hook

To be honest I am confused. I would very much appreciate some teaching regarding the concepts and best practices around this.

Comment: It seems a bit weird for a router to handle the responsibility of showing or not a modal. Why not using a template helper?

Comment: In my application I use onrendered function to show modals, I read hash from the router like '/url#showmodal', if hash found I show modal otherwise not and also in onrendered function the dom will be ready and you have your modal in dom to show

Comment: Like others mention, do not use the router to do this. The router should only be used to route the current user to a template based on the path and any security checks that have been passed, and to send data to that template. Any other logic should be done in the template callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was wondering if the router is the best place. If I don't want to create an onrendered for every template which shows the modal, but place my modal call in the onrendered for the underlying layout template, then it only gets called once and never again. Do you have ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Router.current()` in a reactive computation which opens the modal every time the route changes?

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function () {
  var c = this.autorun(function () {
    Router.current();

    // Launch your modal here
    var userSettings = Meteor.user().profile.settings;
    if(userSettings.showHelp) {
      // Opens modal after template is updated
      Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
        $('#modal').modal();
      });
    }
  });

  // Close existing modal when route changes
  c.onInvalidate(function () {
    $('#modal').hide();
  });
});
```

You can change `Template.myTemplate` to a layout template or even to `Template.body` if this modal is used for all routes.

I have included a working example at https://github.com/xamfoo/meteor-route-based-modal

Comment: I tried this. I navigate to a route A and the modal shows. I navigate to route B and the modal shows. I navigate back to route A and the page gets covered by the modal's overlay, but the modal itself doesn't show, thus making any interactions with the page impossible.

Comment: Bootstrap modals are tricky to deal with in Meteor. I updated the answer with code to deal with unclosed modals and a repo with a working example. Hope it helps!